# Matrix of Char in C - Using Scanf or getchar

Tags: c

i'm having a litle trouble with input info on a matrix

i want to build a simple wordsearch game. The user tells the dimension of the matrix to the wordsearch and inputs the characters and i want to print it just to see if everything is okey with the info.

This is my code:

```
void main (){
int nl, nc, i,j;

scanf ("%d %d", &nl,&nc); //Input number of lines and collums of the matrix

char matrix [nl] [nc];

for (i=0;i<nl;i++)
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
            scanf("%c",&matrix[i][j]);   //Input matrix

printf("This is your matrix:\n");
for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nc; j++)
       printf("%c", matrix [i][j]);
}
```

If i input something like

```
2 3
ABC
DEF
```

The output should be:

```
This is your Matrix:
ABC
DEF
```

But my output when i print is something like

```
This is your Matrix:

ABC
D
```

It first gives a "\n" then prints but not complete.

What am i doing wrong? Please take in consideration that i should only be using functions like scanf and getchar to build the matrix.

Comment: `void main` should be `int main`. You should also ensure your input succeeds.

Comment: Hi @chris, I know about the main, but my gcc compiles with void,so no problem there. Isn't my input succeeding like this?

Comment: Do not use `scanf()`.  Read the line via `fgets()` and then parse the buffer with `sscanf()` or `strtol()`  ( only be using functions like scanf and getchar is an unfortunate but artificial constraint.)

Comment: @chux I have not learned the fgets function in class so i can't do that.

Comment: Check the result of `scanf()` then.  If it is 2, all is good.

Comment: Change `scanf("%c"` to `scanf(" %c"`  (Add space)

Comment: @chux what do you mean? I've put an example of the output above. What do you mean if it's 2? Problem is with printing the matrix

Comment: How is it that you are giving variables as array size?

Comment: @Zindarod It's no problem to use a variable to define the size of the array, but only if you get the value to that variable first. I mean the size of the array it's not define until you input the variable values. Once you change the values of the variables, the size of the array won't change.

Comment: @PedroLino I only know c++11 that you can declare variable length arrays.

Comment: @Zindarod well, it's working form e at least... LOL But if you could suggest another solution i would gladly appreciate it :)

Comment: Why is this tagged as C, C++ and C#?  Are you creating a new language from the common elements of all of them?  Looks like you are programming in C.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMatthews, well you are right about C. But i guess this applies to C++ and C# to, or am i wrong?

Comment: Which language are you programming in?  The C language does not have `string` type.  The C# language has `String`.  By your logic, you should include other languages that are similar:  Objective C, F, and C--.  You would inject fewer defects if you picked a language, and set your tools for that language.  Don't worry about mixing languages, as that is a low probability.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Who ever used the word "strings" here? You where the only one talking about that... And my code doesn't have string tipes anywhere. We are talking about 2D arrays of char.

Comment: Looks like you missed the boat by a long shot.  The point is that C, C++ and C# are different langauges and you pick one language and stick with it.  Another difference between the languages:  references and pointers.  The C language has pointers but not references.  The C++ has both pointers and references.  The C# language uses references and pointers are very difficult to use.

Comment: @Pedro Lino The comment to suggest checking if `scanf()` result is 2 is to verify that indeed your code read the first 2 row and column numbers correctly.  Although it is not the only issue with this code, user input needs to be fully vetted, else subsequent code success of failure is in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP: "What am i doing wrong?"
A: `scanf("%c", ..` is reading `'\n'` left over from the previous `scanf ("%d%d"...`  To avoid that and other white-spaces, consume them by pre-pending a `' '` in the `"%c"` format.

1) Check `scanf()` results.

2) Use Space before `"%c"` to consume whitespace, especially the previous line's `\n`.

3) Use `main()` correctly.

4) Better to use fputs() or puts() when simply printing a string

Edit: Meet ability to enter a scant line

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void ConsumeToEOL(void) {
  int ch;
  do {
    ch = getchar();
  } while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

int main() {
  int nl, nc, i, j;
  // Space between "%d %d" not really needed
  if (scanf("%d%d", &nl, &nc) != 2) {
    fputs("Bad number Input\n", stdout);
    exit(1);
  }
  ConsumeToEOL();

  char matrix[nl][nc];
  for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < nc; j++) {
      int ch = getchar();
      if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
        break;
      matrix[i][j] = (char) ch;
    }
    if (j == nc) ConsumeToEOL();
    for (; j < nc; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  // Better to use fputs() or puts() when simply printing a string
  fputs("This is your matrix:\n", stdout);
  for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < nc; j++) {
      if (matrix[i][j]) {
        printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
    // Add EOL
    fputs("\n", stdout);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @chux, it works, but i have another problem now. Imagine that i only want to put ABC<enter>B<enter> on the input. It doesn't stop asking for chars until i fill it all out. I want to be able to only put one char in one line for example. How would i do that?

Comment: @Pedro Lino Please specify what you want the _other_ values in that matrix row to have if only the first one is specified.

Comment: @Pedro Lino They could be nulls (`'\0'`), but then do you wants them printed out?  How about spaces `' '`?

Comment: Nah, no printing :P When \0 just jump to the next line. :)

Comment: I won't use this code as it is, but it helped a lot. I found my desired solution. Thank you @chux :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip newlines. If you know only scanf, then you can do it as follows::

```
char dummy;
scanf("%d %d", &nl,&nc);
scanf("%c", &dummy);  \\ newline is consumed here.
```

and the same for the newline after each line, so for reading the matrix:

```
for (i=0;i<nl;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
        scanf("%c",&matrix[i][j]);   //Input matrix
    scanf("%c", &dummy);
}
```

Comment: Hi there @Marian... Could i put that in the for cicle? Like, j<nc && matrix [i][j]!='\n'? Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe will help:

```
int main()
{
int nl, nc, i,j;

scanf ("%d %d", &nl,&nc); //Input number of lines and collums of the matrix

char* matrix=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*nl*nc);

char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*nl);


for (i=0;i<nl;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",s);
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
        matrix[i*nl+j]=s[j];
}
printf("This is your matrix:\n");
for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < nc; j++)
       printf("%c", matrix [i*nl+j]);
    printf("\n");
}


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi @Zindarod, i get errors using "New". It's says it's undeclared.

Comment: @PedroLino You have to include stdlib.h for malloc().

Comment: can't use malloc sorry. I haven't learned about memory allocation outside the stack

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void main (){
int nl, nc, i,j;

scanf ("%d %d\n", &nl,&nc); //Input number of lines and collums of the matrix

char matrix [nl] [nc];

for (i=0;i<nl;i++){
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
            scanf("%c",&matrix[i][j]);   //Input matrix
    scanf("\n");
}
printf("This is your matrix:\n");
for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nc; j++)
       printf("%c", matrix [i][j]);
}
```

Comment: Close man close. It deletes the \n at the begining, but it doesn't print the F. Only "DE" :P

Comment: Doesn't work. It removes the \n when printing, and it messes up the number of lines in the input too. If i want to input 2 lines it asks for 3 at least

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
        int nl, nc, i,j;

        scanf ("%d %d\n", &nl,&nc); //Input number of lines and collums of the matrix

        char* matrix = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*nl*nc);

        for (i=0;i<nl;i++) {
                char c;
                for (j=0;j<nc;j++) {
                        scanf("%c",&matrix[i*nc+j]);   //Input matrix
                }
                scanf("%c", &c);
        }

        printf("This is your matrix:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < nc; j++)
                        printf("%c", matrix [i*nc+j]);
                printf("\n");
        }

        free(matrix);
        return 0; }
```

Comment: Can't use malloc, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you originally tagged this as C++, this should help:

```
unsigned int rows;
unsigned int columns;
cin >> rows;
cin >> columns;
std::vector<char> matrix(rows * columns);
for (unsigned int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
  std::string row_text;
  getline(cin, row_text);
  for (unsigned int c = 0; c < columns; ++c)
  {
    matrix.push_back(row_text[c]);
  }
}

for (unsigned int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
{
  for (unsigned int col = 0; col < columns; ++col)
  {
    cout << matrix[row * columns + col];
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. I'll delete c++ from the tags so you stop telling me about it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (){
        int nl, nc, i,j;

        scanf ("%d %d\n", &nl,&nc); //Input number of lines and collums of the matrix

        char matrix [nl][nc];

        for (i=0;i<nl;i++) {
                char c;
                for (j=0;j<nc;j++) {
                        scanf("%c",&matrix[i][j]);   //Input matrix
                }
                scanf("%c", &c);
        }

        printf("This is your matrix:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < nc; j++)
                        printf("%c", matrix [i][j]);
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One Out :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int r, c, i, j;
    printf("Rows = ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Col = ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    char a[r][c];
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("Alphabet in row %d and column %d = ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf(" %c", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n Given Matrix :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf(" %c ", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
// End of main.
```

This one should definitely work fine!

*NOTE :
Notice --> scanf(" %c", &a[i][j]);
           Here a space is given before %c so as to consume the white space.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might find you the way.
(Same code you published with little Modifications)

```
void main (){
int nl, nc, i,j;

scanf ("%d %d", &nl,&nc); //Input number of lines and columns of the matrix

char matrix [nl] [nc];

for (i=0;i<nl;i++)
    for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
        scanf("%s",&matrix[i][j]);   //Input matrix ***GIVE INPUT IN FORM OF STRING THAT IS '%s' ***

printf("This is your matrix:\n");
for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nc; j++)
            printf("%c", matrix [i][j]);
        printf("\n");                      // USE '\n' FOR NEXT FOR SUCCESSFUL OUTPUT OF YOUR CODE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   char matrix[n][n];
   for(int ctr1=0; ctr1<n; ctr1++)
       for(int ctr2=0; ctr2<n; ctr2++)
            scanf("\n%c",&matrix[ctr1][ctr2]);

   for(int ctr1=0; ctr1<n; ctr1++)
   {
       for(int ctr2=0; ctr2<n; ctr2++)
           printf("%c ", matrix[ctr1][ctr2]);
       printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<nl;i++)
for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
        scanf(" %c",&matrix[i][j]);
```

In the scanf statement, Add a space before the %c inside the double quotes.
The machine takes a enter (ASCII) value as a character. Hence when we press enter key or when we leave a space, it may taken as a char value (ASCII value of enter or space as machine knows only ASCII).